# After any execution temporary error comes out ,How to fix error in temporary directory

Tags: warning-messages, error-trapping

how can I repair this error that started to come out of nowhere, I have not made any changes in the equipment but mathematica accuses that error

```
 General::cdir: "Cannot set current directory to \!\(\"C:\\\\Users\\\\HELP\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\temp\\\\m-68013f32-c103-48e0-ac7b-8cd1385c8fdc\"\). \!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\", Appearance->{Automatic, None}, BaseStyle->\"Link\", ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/message/General/cdir\", ButtonNote->\"General::cdir\"]\)"
```

Comment: I’d try Wolfram Support for this.

Comment: Check that all of these directories are real on disk and you have permission to access them: `$HomeDirectory
$BaseDirectory
$UserBaseDirectory
$UserDocumentsDirectory
$InitialDirectory
$RootDirectory
$InstallationDirectory`

Comment: @ flinty   thanks  , is there a way to permanently designate mathematica a different directory